# How to escape the tailwindcss responsive syntax when using with contact form 7?

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using the responsive syntax of tailwindcss for different screen size and when I am using it with Contact Form 7 (CF7) the syntax is getting ignored by CF7.

```
[text* fullname id:fullname class:w-full class:text-center class:text-white class:placeholder-white  class:bg-black class:py-3 class:sm:py-6 placeholder "Name"]
```

i will get the output like this

```
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required w-full text-center text-white placeholder-white bg-black py-3" id="fullname" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name">
```

the `class:sm:py-6` is getting ignored. same for all the colon based syntax. How do I escape it from being ignored by CF7?

Comment: not possible to have a colon in a cf7 class.  If you need a responsive cf7 form, use the [Smart Grid-layout plugin extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/)